# How can I check if string contains a certain letter followed by anything other than itself or vowels?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, include

I am trying to achieve the following:

Check if a string contains the letter `n` immediately followed by anything other than another `n` or `vowels` (so, consonants (except n), punctuation, spaces...)

If it does, replace that `n` for another character (`X`, for example), keeping everything else.

`nja!` would become `Xja!`

`nnja!` would become `nXja!`

`n ja!` would become `X ja!`

...

Comment: Have you got any code yet?

Comment: Not yet. I have very little knowledge of RegEx. I am still wrapping my head around how to approach this, and what information to look for and study...

Answer (score 1):

Because strings are immutable you will need to splice the string or turn the string into a list before replacing.

Comment: And how would I do that? My idea was having something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1yc4kp29/

Comment: This is not an answer.